Are public contact details allowed on a TSE profile?
IIRC, in a now deleted comment on this question, user Saransh Sharma appeared to be a) encouraging personal contact between themselves and the OP and b) offering to recommend immigration advice services.
Subsequently, the user added two more comments:

the OP should add a public profile or a contact on their profile and

Personal contact is not allowed but if user wishes to be connected then what’s wrong with that


Is this in accordance with TSE policy? I may have misunderstood, however a public profile or contact that facilitates off-site contact between users seems questionable to me.

As far as I understand it is not allowed, it is surely discouraged.

I have asked more moderators and staff in a chatroom and the answer is that it is not against the rules to post contact details.
It is also very much discouraged to contact fellow users outside the on site chatrooms, this is to protect all involved users.
As suggested by @rene:
In context with the question the advice is clear but to prevent being mis-quotted maybe expand to it is not against the rules to post contact details in your own "about me". Everywhere else: posts, comments, chat, it is off-limits.
